# Unity Array issue

Tags: multidimensional-array, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I have an array:

```
var playpicks2 = new Array("000", "001", "002");
```

and arrays within array:

```
var allwinning = new Array(
["000", "001", "002"],
["000", "010", "020"],
["000", "011", "022"],...);
var playpicks = allwins[0];
```

and this is what I want to do:

```
if(playpicks==playpicks2)
{
print("yes they are matched");
}
else
{
print("No No No!");
}
// and I always get "No No No!"
```

When I `print(playpicks2)` I get

```
000,001,002
```

but when I `print(playpicks)` I get

```
System.String[]
```

How can I resolve this?? is there a straight forward way to convert `String[]` into normal array like `playpicks2`? Thanks!

Comment: Don't use `new Array`, use array literals.

Comment: Where is `playpick` in your code?

Comment: I think you meant to do `print(playpicks)`, not `print(playpick)`.

Comment: Yes. What is array literals? any example?

Comment: `System.String[]`??? That doesn't sound like a JavaScript built-in to me.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting "No No No" because arrays are reference types. [1,2] === [1,2] will return false because they do not refer to the same object. To check array equality, use a library like jquery or underscore.

http://underscorejs.org/#isEqual

Also, using the Array constructor is messy. Why not use literals?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of relying on JQuery or whatever miracle tool to get rid of the nuisance, I would rather try to pinpoint what is causing the problem.

Basically, the == operator does only a shallow equality test. It will not test each value of the array, only the global array reference.

In your case, the arrays contain the same literal values, but they are still different objects, so the == comparison fails.

A general in-depth comparison function or a miracle JQuery include could solve the problem, but that would be using an A-bomb to kill an ant.

Here I would advise you to use the toString() method on each array, [like this fiddle shows](http://jsfiddle.net/Xwz8s/1/):

```
var playpicks2 = ["000", "001", "002"];

var allwinning = [
["000", "001", "002"],
["000", "010", "020"],
["000", "011", "022"]];
var playpicks = allwinning[0];

// shallow comparison fails, though console.log shows identical strings
if(playpicks==playpicks2)
    console.log("yes they are matched");
else
    console.log("No No No! ["+playpicks+"] / ["+playpicks2+"]");

// string value comparison succeeds
if(playpicks.toString()==playpicks2.toString())
    console.log("yes they are matched: "+playpicks.toString());
else
    console.log("No No No! ["+playpicks+"] / ["+playpicks2+"]");
```

As other noted, I used the literal aray notation, which is perfectly equivalent to yours, only a bit more compact.

I also used the console.log debug function, so you'll have to activate the console to see something in the fiddle.

Comment: Using toString() to test array equality is a bad general purpose method because it will not work for arrays of objects, as the contained objects will become '[Object object]'. Using libraries to do this kind of thing is idiomatic. Also, [[3],[4,5]].toString() === [[3,4],[5]].toString() === [3,4,5]

Comment: Of course it's a bad general purpose method. As a matter of fact, it's not general purpose at all. It seems well suited to the task at hand, though. The day the winning picks will be coded as [[3],[4,5]] and [[3,4],[5]] and represent different values, it will be time to switch to JQuery or whatever. But that would require a complete overhaul of the program, and by then comparing two picks would likely be the least of the OP's problems. Choosing the right tool for the job requires more work than carpet bombing the problem, but it pays off handsomely in the end, or so experience told me.

Comment: Hi, I cannot use literal because the elements in the array is dynamic.

Comment: Ah sure, but still you could initialize your array with `[]` instead of `new Array()`. Anyway, the only objective advantage of the brackets is to reduce slightly the size of your JS source, which is always a good thing, but not important enough to force you to use it IMHO.